# NodeJS MongoDB mongoose db.open do not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888,"myIp");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/troll1');
var db = mongoose.connection;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('registerForm', function (data) {
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function callback () {
          socket.emit('registerFormConfirm',{"ok":1});
        });

    });
});
```

OK, that code is in mine server.js. For some reason emit is not working, below code is working normaly:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888,"myIp");
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('registerForm', function (data) {
        socket.emit('registerFormConfirm',{"ok":1});

    });
});
```

I have installed mongoose normaly, like other packages. Dont know if is there something i can do in terminal to check if it's istalled correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mongoose emits `open` event when call `mongoose.connect`, but your event listener is set too late to capture the event.

Revise your code as

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888,"myIp");
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('registerForm', function (data) {
        db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
        db.once('open', function callback () {
          socket.emit('registerFormConfirm',{"ok":1});
        });
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/troll1'); // connect here

    });
});
```